# Updating checkout validations without typing in the field

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, validation

By default, the validations on checkout fields get updated on "keyup" of the field you're typing in.

Is there a way to update validations when clicking a button or by some other action, that is not- directly typing in the field?